# How to Align Vector Layer on QGIS cloud Imageries for Printing

Tags: qgis-openlayers-plugin, alignment

I noticed a weird problem every time I save maps with either Bing or Google Imageries from QGIS Cloud. The vector features all align perfectly well on the map canvas and even on print composer. But after saving the map as either .jpg or .pdf, the vector layer on the saved map file would have shifted by a huge margin.

Please see picture attached.

[image]

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Don't use the OpenLayers plugin. Use QuickMapServices.

Comment: Many thanks Nathan W, seems like my problem has been solved. Very grateful.